# How do I do Conditional formatting on Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a spreadsheet where a user is to choose a job title from a drop down list and the according to that job title certain cells are highlighted with appropriate training course.

For example Job title chose is General Manager on Column B6 Highlight column M6 R6 S6 T6 (corresponding row) yellow

Does this make sense?

If a different job title different cells will need to be highlighted but I just want to get the basics right first.

Comment: Voting to close because this is not a real question. Record a macro while you do this. If you still have trouble, post a new question including your code, and explaining why it is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way you can do that without macro, if you can access the dropdown list value from formulas.

So, that's how you do it:

Create a new column where you will be marking with an `x` the courses that apply to that Job.
You can title that column like `Recomended Training Courses`.

In that column, make a formula using the dropdown value.
Example: if value is `Programmer`, the line with `VBA Course` will have an `x`. Else, just a nothing text: `""`.

This way, you don't need to do code for conditional formatting, just do the formatting based on this column containing the `x` values.

You can also maintain a second sheet containing the `Courses (columns)` x `Jobs (lines)`.
In that table you mark the `x` for all jobs and courses that are related.

And your formula will be based in this table instead of being based on text names.

Relation table example:

```
     A                 B           C          D        E
1  ----              Programmer  Manager  Cleaner    Programming Teacher
2 VBA                   x                              x
3  C#                   x                              x
4 People relations                 x                   x
5  Using Mops                               x
```

This table will help A LOT with the formulas for filling the `Recomended Training Courses` column with the `x` values.

(Of course you may need to adjust this table according to your main table formatting, if courses are in lines or columns, so, if you show an example of your sheet formatting, this answer can be updated to better ways)